# The operator '>' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart, null

```
          itemCount: (widget.userbio.resimler?.length!=null) ? 0:(widget.userbio.resimler?.length!>9)?9:widget.userbio.resimler?.length,
```

error:

```
error: The operator '>' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. (unchecked_use_of_nullable_value at [ui_profile_instagram] lib\pages\profile.dart:220)
```

hello how to fix this error ?

```
widget.userbio.resimler?.length!>9
```

ı need compare

Comment: Does: `itemCount: (widget.userbio.resimler?.length ?? 0 > 9) ? 9 : widget.userbio.resimler?.length` work?

Comment: error: Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'. (non_bool_condition at [ui_profile_instagram] lib\pages\profile.dart:220)

Comment: I think you should study about nullable field. This error says, it may happen a case where widget.userbio.resimilar?.length is null, you check null with 0 which is not a possible!  So you have to return something when it is null. Like @MendelG says,   you can try with this also `itemCount: (widget.userbio.resimler?.length! ?? 0) >9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to change it to `widget.userbio.resimler!.length!`.

The long answer is to introduce a local variable. Something like:

```
final l = widget.userbio.resimler?.length;
```

You can then test `l` for null and the compiler will know that after you've tested it, it can't be null. (Note this only works for local variables - hence why you should add one.)

```
if (l != null) {/* in this block l cannot be null*/}
```

so

```
final l = widget.userbio.resimler?.length;
itemCount: l == null ? 0 : l > 9 ? 9 : l;
```

Best of all user a null aware operator:

```
var l = widget.userbio.resimler?.length ?? 0;
if (l > 9) l = 9;
```